# HTML form validation with SASS?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a form where all the input fields has a 'required' and 'pattern' argument.

I would like to show a small green picture on the right of the inputbox, whenever the input is not invalid, to show the user he has filled it correctly.

Im wondering if its possible to do without javascript/jquery and instead with pure css/sass?

I was thinking something like

```
if input:invalid{
    .divonrightofinputbox{
    background:url('green.png');
    }
}else{
    .divonrightofinputbox{
    display:none;
    }
}
```

Is this possible with sass and if so, how? :)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sass knows nothing about the document or the state of its forms.  You just have to use what CSS offers:

```
input {
    &:required {
        + .div-after-the-input {
            // required styles
        }
    }

    &:invalid, &:out-of-range {
        + .div-after-the-input {
            background: url('invalid.png') no-repeat;
        }
    }

    &:valid, &:in-range {
        + .div-after-the-input {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry Im a little new to SASS, is it possible to put another nest on your CSS above? Like placing  .divonrightofinputbox{
    background:url('green.png'); underneath &:valid and display:none under invalid?

Comment: You're free to nest as far as you want (for practical purposes, don't go *too* far).  I've updated my answer so you can see.